# Is there any implementation of this string matching method in python?

Tags: python, string, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-comparison

I am trying to work out which entries in my data store are near-duplicates using approximate string matching.

Is there any implementation of the following approach in python, or do i need to try and roll my own?

Thanks :)

[from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching#Overview):

> ...
>
> A brute-force approach would be to
>   compute the edit distance to P for all
>   substrings of T, and then choose the
>   substring with the minimum distance.
>   However, this algorithm would have the
>   running time O(n3 m)
>
> A better solution[3][4], utilizing
>   dynamic programming, uses an
>   alternative formulation of the
>   problem: for each position j in the
>   text T and each position i in the
>   pattern P, compute the minimum edit
>   distance between the i first
>   characters of the pattern, Pi, and any
>   substring Tj',j of T that ends at
>   position j.

What is the most efficient way to apply this to many strings?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
google("python levenshtein")
```

Answer (score 1):

[difflib.get_close_matches](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

`difflib` might be the answer, eg,

```
from difflib import context_diff

a = 'acaacbaaca'
b = 'accabcaacc'

print ''.join(context_diff(a,b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Levenshtein distance performs very similarly to the fuzzywuzzy standard ratio() function. fuzzywuzzy uses difflib http://seatgeek.com/blog/dev/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python

example from the fuzzywuzzy documentation:
https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy

```
fuzz.ratio("this is a test", "this is a test!")
    96
```